# How can I embed Traditional Chinese characters in an actionscript project?

Tags: actionscript-3, cjk, embedded-fonts, tlf

I'm having some issue with embedding Traditional Chinese characters from the Arial Unicode MS font. I've used the character set described [here](http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0) (0x4E00 - 0x4FFF).
I will need to display text using the TextLayoutFramework(TLF) and I've done a couple of tests:

- [embedding characters with Flash](http://lifesine.eu/test/ChineseEmbedTestTLF.swf)
- [embedding characters with Flex](http://lifesine.eu/test/FontTest.html)

With Flash, regular TextField seems to display the characters, but the TLFTextField bellow seems to use only a few embedded characters, while the majority are using Device Font.

With Flex, there is a similar issue - not all characters seem embedded.

Has anyone come across this issue ? Has anyone successfully embedded Traditional Chinese characters in an actionscript application ? If so, how ?

**Update**

The source for Flash embedding is available [here](http://lifesine.eu/test/ChineseEmbedTestTLF.fla)
and here is the generated size report and output using @MPD's suggestion:

```
ChineseEmbedTestTLF.swf Movie Report
-------------------------------------

Preloader SWF Wrapping Content SWF
----------------------------------

Metadata
--------
Bytes         Value
----------    -----
      1289    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"> <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Flash Professional CS5</xmp:CreatorTool> <xmp:CreateDate>2011-05-26T13:27:34+01:00</xmp:CreateDate> <xmp:MetadataDate>2011-06-03T15:02:29+01:00</xmp:MetadataDate> <xmp:ModifyDate>2011-06-03T15:02:29+01:00</xmp:ModifyDate> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <dc:format>application/x-shockwave-flash</dc:format> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"> <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:6116DFD92320681192B0C301A9D3C200</xmpMM:InstanceID> <xmpMM:DocumentID>xmp.did:6116DFD92320681192B0C301A9D3C200</xmpMM:DocumentID> <xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>xmp.did:F77F1174072068118A6DF79BB8EEF8A7</xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom rdf:parseType="Resource"> <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:FD7F11740720681192B0C301A9D3C200</stRef:instanceID> <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:BA7F153228206811871FEE12E85703CB</stRef:documentID> <stRef:originalDocumentID>xmp.did:F77F1174072068118A6DF79BB8EEF8A7</stRef:originalDocumentID> </xmpMM:DerivedFrom> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> 

Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene
-------    -----------    -----------    -----
      1           9786           9786    Scene 1
      2        4352002        4361788    Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)

Scene      Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
Scene 1             48             0                  8718

ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
              8345    Scene 1:Frame 1
               373    Scene 1:Frame 2

Binary Data              Bytes         Location
---------------------    ----------    --------
Loading Animation SWF          1264    Scene 1:Frame 1
Content SWF                 4351569    Scene 1:Frame 2


Content SWF
-----------

Metadata
--------
Bytes         Value
----------    -----
      1088    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"> <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Flash Professional CS5</xmp:CreatorTool> <xmp:CreateDate>2011-05-26T13:27:34+01:00</xmp:CreateDate> <xmp:MetadataDate>2011-06-03T15:02:07+01:00</xmp:MetadataDate> <xmp:ModifyDate>2011-06-03T15:02:07+01:00</xmp:ModifyDate> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <dc:format>application/x-shockwave-flash</dc:format> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"> <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:6016DFD92320681192B0C301A9D3C200</xmpMM:InstanceID> <xmpMM:DocumentID>xmp.did:6016DFD92320681192B0C301A9D3C200</xmpMM:DocumentID> <xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>xmp.did:F77F1174072068118A6DF79BB8EEF8A7</xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom rdf:parseType="Resource"> <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:FD7F11740720681192B0C301A9D3C200</stRef:instanceID> <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:BA7F153228206811871FEE12E85703CB</stRef:documentID> <stRef:originalDocumentID>xmp.did:F77F1174072068118A6DF79BB8EEF8A7</stRef:originalDocumentID> </xmpMM:DerivedFrom> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> 

Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene
-------    -----------    -----------    -----
      1        4353570        4353570    Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)

Scene      Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
Scene 1              0            48                 74611

Font Name         Bytes         Characters
--------------    ----------    ----------
ArialUnicodeMS       2852170     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~·‐‑‒–—―‖‗‘’‚‛“”„․‥…○　、。〃〄々〆〇〈〉《》「」『』【】〒〓〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞一丁七丈三上下不丐丑且丕世丘丙丞丟並丫中丰串丸丹主乃久么之乍乎乏乒乓乖乘乙九乞也乩乳乾亂了予事二于云互五井亙些亞亟亡亢交亥亦亨享京亭亮亳人什仁仃仄仆仇今介仍仔仕他仗付仙仞仟代令以仰仲仳件任份仿企伉伊伋伍伏伐休伕伙伯估伴伶伸伺似伽佃但佇佈位低住佐佑佔何佗余佚佛作佝佞你佣佩佬佯佰佳併佺佻佾使侃來侈例侍侏侑侖供依侮侯侵侶侷便係促俄俊俎俏俐俑俗俘俚保俞俟俠信修俯俱俳俸俺俾倀倆倉個倌倍倏們倒倔倖倘候倚借倡倣倥倦倨倩倪倫倭值偃假偉偌偎偏偕做停健偭偯側偵偶偷偺偽傀傅傍傑傖傘備傚傢催傭傯傲傳債傷傻傾僅僇僎像僑僕僖僚僥僧僩僭僮僱僵價僻儀儂億儅儈儉儐儒儔儕儘償儡優儲儳儷儸儻儼儿兀允元兄充兆兇先光克兌免兒兔兕兗兜兢入內全兩八公六兮共兵其具典兼冀冉冊再冑冒冕冗冠冢冤冥冪冬冰冶冷冽准凋凌凍凜凝几凡凰凱凳凶凸凹出函刀刁刃分切刈刊刎刑划刖列初判別刨利刪刮到制刷券刺刻剁剃則削剋剌前剎剔剖剛剜剝剩剪副割剴創剷剽剿劂劃劇劈劉劊劍劑劓力功加劣助努劫劬劻劾勁勃勇勉勒動勗勘務勛勝勞募勢勣勤勦勰勳勵勸勺勻勾勿包匆匈匍匏匐匕化北匙匝匠匡匣匪匯匱匹匾匿區十千卅升午卉半卑卒卓協南博卜卞占卡卦卮卯印危即卵卷卸卹卻卿厄厚厝原厥厭厲去參又叉及友反叔取受叛叟叢口古句另叨叩只叫召叭叮可台叱史右叵司叻叼吁吃各吆合吉吊吋同名后吏吐向吒君吝吞吟吠否吧吩含听吭吮吱吳吵吶吸吹吻吼吾呀呂呃呆呈告呎呢周呱味呵呶呷呸呻呼命咀咄咆咋和咎咐咒咕咖咚咦咧咨咩咪咫咬咯咱咳咸咻咽咿哀品哂哄哇哈哉哎員哥哦哨哩哪哭哮哲哺哼哽唁唆唇唉唏唐唔唧唬售唯唱唳唷唸唾啁啃啄商啊問啕啖啗啜啞啟啡啣啤啦啪啻啼啾喀喂喃善喇喉喊喋喔喘喙喚喜喝喟喧喪喫喬單喱喲喳喻嗅嗆嗇嗉嗎嗑嗓嗚嗜嗟嗡嗣嗤嗥嗦嗨嗯嗶嗷嗽嗾嘀嘆嘈嘉嘍嘎嘐嘔嘖嘗嘛嘟嘩嘮嘯嘰嘲嘴嘶嘹嘻嘿噎噓噗噙噢噤噥器噩噪噫噬噯噱噴噶噸噹嚀嚅嚇嚎嚏嚐嚕嚥嚨嚮嚴嚶嚷嚼囀囁囂囈囉囊囌囑囚四囝回因囤囪囫困固囿圃圄圈圉國圍園圓圖團土在圩圬圭圯地圳圻圾址均坊坍坎坏坐坑坡坤坦坩坪坷坼垂垃型垓垠垢垣垮埂埃埋城埔域埠埤執培基堂堅堆堉堊堝堠堡堤堪堯堰報場堵塊塋塌塑塒塔塗塘塚塞塢填塭塵塹塽塾墀境墅墊墓墜增墟墦墨墩墮墳墾壁壅壇壎壑壓壕壘壙壞壟壢壤壩士壬壯壹壺壽夏夔夕外夙多夜夠夢夤夥大天太夫夭央失夷夸夾奄奇奈奉奎奏奐契奔奕套奘奚奠奢奧奩奪奭奮女奴奶奸她好妁如妃妄妊妍妒妓妖妙妝妞妣妤妥妨妮妯妳妹妻妾姅姆姊始姍姐姑姒姓委姘姚姜姣姥姦姨姪姬姻姿威娃娉娌娑娓娘娛娜娟娠娣娥娩娶娼婀婁婆婉婊婚婢婦婪婷婿媒媚媛媧媲媳媼媽媾嫁嫂嫉嫌嫖嫗嫘嫡嫣嫦嫩嫵嫻嬈嬉嬋嬌嬝嬤嬪嬰嬴嬸孀孃子孑孓孔孕字存孚孛孜孝孟季孤孩孫孰孱孳孵學孺孽孿它宅宇守安宋完宏宗官宙定宛宜客宣室宥宦宮宰害宴宵家宸容宿寂寄寅密寇富寐寒寓寞察寡寢寤寥實寧寨審寫寬寮寰寵寶寸寺封射將專尉尊尋對導小少尖尚尢尤尬就尷尸尹尺尼尾尿局屁居屆屈屋屍屎屏屐屑展屘屜屝屠屢層履屨屬屯山屹岌岐岑岔岡岩岫岱岳岷岸峒峙峨峪峭峰峴島峻峽崁崆崇崎崑崔崖崗崙崛崢崤崧崩崴嵇嵌嵐嵩嵯嶄嶇嶔嶝嶸嶺嶼嶽巉巍巒巔巖川州巡巢工左巧巨巫差己已巳巴巷巽巾市布帆希帑帕帖帘帚帛帝帟帥師席帳帶帷常帽幀幃幅幌幔幕幗幛幟幡幢幣幫干平年并幸幹幻幼幽幾庇床序底庖店庚府庠度座庫庭庵庶康庸庾廁廂廄廈廉廊廓廖廚廝廟廠廢廣廬廳延廷建廾廿弁弄弈弊弋式弒弓弔引弗弘弛弟弦弧弩弭弱張強弼彆彈彊彌彎彗彙彝形彤彥彩彪彫彬彭彰影彷役彼彿往征待徇很徉徊律後徐徑徒得徘徙徜從徠御徨復循徬微徵德徹徽心必忌忍忖志忘忙忝忠忪快忱念忸忽忿怎怏怒怔怕怖怛思怠怡急性怨怩怪怫怯怵恃恆恍恐恕恙恢恣恤恥恨恩恪恫恬恭息恰恿悄悅悉悌悍悔悖悚悟悠患您悲悴悵悶悸悻悼悽情惆惇惋惑惕惘惚惜惟惠惡惦惰惱想惴惶惹惺惻愀愁愆愈愉愍愎意愒愕愚愛愜感愣愧愴愷愾愿慄慇慈態慌慍慎慕慘慚慝慟慢慣慧慨慫慮慰慵慶慷慼慾憂憊憎憐憑憔憚憤憧憩憫憬憮憲憶憾懂懇懈應懊懋懍懣懦懲懵懶懷懸懺懼懾懿戀戈戊戌戍戎成我戒戕或戚戛戟戡戢截戮戰戲戳戴戶戾房所扁扇扈扉手才扎扑扒打扔托扛扣扭扮扯扳扶批扼找承技抄抆抉把抑抒抓投抖抗折抨披抬抱抵抹押抽抿拂拄拆拇拈拉拋拌拍拎拐拒拓拔拖拗拘拙拚招拜括拭拮拯拱拳拴拷拼拽拾拿持挂指挈按挑挖挨挪挫振挺挽挾捂捆捉捌捍捎捏捐捕捧捨捩捫捱捲捶捷捺捻掀掃掄授掉掌掏排掖掘掙掛掠採探掣接控推掩措掬揀揆揉揍描提插揖揚換握揣揩揪揭揮援揹搆損搏搓搔搖搗搜搞搪搬搭搴搶搽搾摑摒摔摘摟摧摩摭摯摸摹摺摻撇撈撐撒撓撕撙撚撞撢撤撥撩撫撬播撮撰撲撳撻撼撾撿擁擂擄擅擇擊擋操擎擒擔擘據擠擢擦擬擭擰擱擲擴擷擺擻擾攀攆攏攔攘攙攜攝攣攤攪攫攬支收攸改攻放政故效敉敏救敔敕敖敗敘教敝敞敢散敦敬敲整敵敷數斂斃文斐斑斕斗料斛斜斟斡斤斥斧斫斬斯新斷方於施旁旅旋旌旎族旖旗既日旦旨早旬旭旱旺昀昂昆昇昊昌明昏易昔昕星映昤春昧昨昭是昱晁時晃晅晉晌晏晒晚晝晞晤晦晨普景晰晴晶晷智晾暄暇暈暉暍暑暖暗暘暝暢暨暫暮暱暴暸暹曄曆曇曉曖曙曜曝曠曦曩曬曰曲曳更曷書曹曼曾替最會月有朋服朔朕朗望朝期朦朧木未末本札朮朱朴朵朽杆杉李杏材村杓杖杗杜杞束杠杪杭杯杰東杲杳杵杷杼松板枇枉枋析枓枕林枚果枝枯枰枴架枸柄柏某柑柒染柔柙柚柝柞柢查柩柬柯柱柳柴柵柿栓栗栘校栩株核根格栽桀桁桂桃桅框案桌桐桑桓桔桶桿梁梂梃梅梆梓梔梗條梟梡梢梧梨梭梯械梱梳梵棄棉棋棍棒棕棗棘棚棟棠棣棧森棲棵棹棺棻椅植椎椒椰楊楓楔楚楛楝楞楠楣楨楫業楮極楷楹概榆榔榕榛榜榣榦榨榫榭榮榴榷榻槁槃構槌槍槐槓槨槭槳槽樁樂樅樊樑樓標樞樟模樣樵樸樹樺樽橄橇橈橋橘橙機橡橢橫橾檀檄檐檔檗檜檠檢檣檬檮檯檳檸檻櫂櫃櫓櫚櫛櫝櫥櫬櫺櫻欄權欐欖欠次欣欲欺欽款歇歉歌歎歐歙歜歟歡止正此步武歧歪歲歷歸歹死歿殃殆殉殊殖殘殤殮殯殲段殷殺殼殿毀毅毆毋母每毒毓比毗毚毛毫毬毯毽氅氈氏氐民氓氖氛氟氣氤氦氧氨氫氬氮氯氳水永氾汀汁求汍汎汐汕汗汙汛汝汞江池污汨汪汰汲汴汶決汽汾沁沂沃沅沆沈沉沌沍沐沒沔沖沘沙沛沫沬沮沱河沸油治沼沽沾沿況泄泅泉泊泌泓法泖泗泛泜泠泡波泣泥注泯泰泱泳泵洋洌洎洗洛洞津洧洩洪洫洮洱洲洵洶洸洹活洽派流浙浚浥浦浩浪浬浮浴海浸浹涅涇消涉涊涌涎涓涔涕涪涮涯液涵涸涼涿淄淅淆淇淋淌淑淒淘淙淚淞淡淤淦淨淪淫淬淮深淳淵混淹淺添清渙渚減渝渠渡渣渤渥渦測渭港渲渴游渺渾湃湄湊湍湎湔湖湘湛湟湣湧湩湮湯湲溉源準溘溜溝溢溥溧溪溫溯溴溶溺溼滂滄滅滇滋滌滑滓滔滕滬滯滲滴滷滾滿漁漂漆漏漓演漕漠漢漣漩漪漫漬漯漱漲漳漸漾漿潑潔潘潛潟潠潤潦潭潮潯潰潸潺潼澀澄澆澈澎澗澠澡澤澦澧澱澳澴澶澹激濁濂濃濕濘濛濟濠濡濤濩濫濬濮濯濰濱濺濾瀆瀉瀋瀏瀑瀕瀘瀚瀛瀝瀟瀨瀰瀲瀾灌灑灘灞灣灤火灰灶灸灼災炊炎炒炕炙炤炫炬炭炮炯炳炸為烈烊烏烘烙烤烯烹烽焉焊焙焚焜無焦焰然煆煉煌煎煖煙煜煞煤煥煦照煨煩煬煮煽熄熊熒熔熙熟熨熬熱熹熾燃燄燈燉燎燐燒燕燙燜營燠燥燦燧燬燭燮燴燸燻燼燾爆爍爐爛爨爪爬爭爰爵父爸爹爺爻爽爾牆片版牌牒牖牘牙牛牝牟牠牡牢牧物牯牲牴特牽犀犁犄犒犖犛犢犧犬犯狀狂狄狎狐狗狙狠狡狩狷狸狹狼狽猓猖猙猛猜猥猩猴猶猷猾猿獄獅獎獐獗獨獰獲獵獷獸獺獻玀玄玆率玉王玖玟玥玨玩玫玲玳玷玻珀珊珍珞珠珪班珮現球琅理琉琊琍琛琢琥琦琨琪琯琳琴琵琶琺琿瑁瑕瑙瑚瑛瑜瑞瑟瑣瑤瑩瑪瑭瑯瑰瑾璀璃璋璘璜璞璟璣璦璧璨璩環璽璿瓊瓏瓔瓖瓚瓜瓠瓢瓣瓤瓦瓶瓷甄甌甍甕甘甚甜生產甥甦用甩甫甬甭田由甲申男甸甽畋界畎畏畔留畚畜畝畢略畦番畫異當畸畿疆疇疊疋疏疑疙疚疝疢疣疤疥疫疲疳疵疸疹疼疽疾痂病症痊痍痔痕痘痙痛痞痠痢痣痰痱痲痳痴痺痿瘀瘁瘉瘋瘍瘓瘟瘠瘡瘢瘤瘦瘧瘩瘴瘸瘺療癆癌癒癖癘癟癡癢癥癩癬癮癱癲癸登發白百皂的皆皇皈皋皎皓皖皚皮皰皴皺皿盂盃盅盆盈益盍盎盒盔盛盜盞盟盡監盤盥盧盪目盯盲直相盹盼盾省眇眉看真眠眨眩眶眷眸眺眼眾睏睛睜睞睡睢督睥睦睨睪睫睬睹睽睿瞄瞇瞋瞌瞎瞑瞞瞟瞠瞥瞧瞪瞬瞭瞰瞳瞻瞼瞽瞿矇矓矗矚矛矜矢矣知矩短矮矯石矽砂砌砍研砝砟砠砥砧砭砰砲破砷砸硃硎硝硫硬硯硼硿碉碌碎碑碓碗碘碟碣碧碩碰碳確碼碾磁磅磊磋磐磕磚磧磨磬磯磴磷磺礁礎礙礦礪礫礬示社祀祁祆祇祈祉祐祕祖祗祚祝神祟祠祥票祭祺祿禁禍禎福禦禧禪禮禱禳禹禺禽禾禿秀私秈秉秋科秒秘租秣秤秦秧秩移稀稅稈程稍稔稚稜稞稟稠種稱稷稻稼稽稿穀穆穋穌積穎穗穠穡穢穩穫穴究穹空穿突窄窈窒窕窖窗窘窟窠窩窪窮窯窺窿竄竅竇竊立站竟章竣童竭端競竹竺竽竿笆笑笙笛笞笠符笨第笮筆等筋筍筏筐筑筒答策筠筧筮筵筷箄箇箋箏箔箕算箝箠管箭箱箴箸節篁範篆篇築篌篙篛篠篡篤篦篩篷篾簇簌簍簑簞簡簣簧簪簫簷簸簽簾簿籀籃籌籍籐籟籠籣籤籥籬籮米籽粉粒粕粗粟粥粱粳粵粹粽精糊糕糖糙糜糝糞糟糠糢糧糯糰糸系糾紀紂約紅紆紇紉紊紋納紐純紕紗紙級紛紜素紡索紫紮累細紱紲紳紹紼絀終絃組絆結絕絛絞絡絢給絨絮絰統絲絳絹綁綏綑經綜綞綠綢綬維綰綱網綴綵綸綺綻綽綾綿緇緊緒緘緙線緝緞締緣編緩緬緯緲練緹緻縈縉縊縐縑縛縝縞縣縫縮縯縱縲縴縵縷縹總績縿繁繃繅繆繈繒織繕繙繚繞繡繩繪繫繭繳繹繼繽纂續纏纓纔纖纜缶缸缺缽罄罈罌罐罔罕罟罩罪置罰署罵罷罹羅羈羊羋羌美羔羚羞群羨義羯羲羶羸羹羼羽羿翁翅翌翎習翔翕翟翠翡翩翮翰翱翳翹翻翼耀老考耄者耆耋而耍耐耑耒耕耗耘耙耜耦耨耳耶耽耿聆聊聒聖聘聚聞聯聰聱聲聳聶職聽聾聿肄肅肆肇肉肋肌肓肖肘肚肛肝股肢肥肩肪肫肯肱育肴肺胃胄背胎胖胚胛胝胞胡胤胥胭胯胰胱胳胴胸胼能脂脅脆脈脊脖脣脤脩脫脯脰脹脾腆腋腌腎腐腑腓腔腕腥腦腫腮腰腱腳腴腸腹腺腿膀膂膈膊膏膘膚膛膜膝膠膨膩膳膺膽膾膿臀臂臃臆臉臍臏臘臚臟臢臣臥臧臨自臬臭至致臺臻臼臾舀舂舅與興舉舊舌舍舐舒舔舛舜舞舟舢舨航舫般舵舶舷船艇艋艘艙艦艮良艱色艷艾芋芍芒芙芝芟芣芥芬芭芯芰花芳芷芸芹芻芽芾苑苒苓苔苗苛苜苞苟苣若苦苧苯英茁茂范茄茅茆茉茗茨茫茱茲茴茵茶茸茹荀荃草荊荏荐荒荔荷荸荻荼莆莉莊莎莒莓莖莘莞莠莢莧莫莽菁菅菊菌菔菜菟菠菩華菰菱菲菴菸菽萃萄萇萊萋萌萍萎萬萱萵萸萼落葆葉著葛葡董葦葩葫葬葭葵葷蒂蒐蒙蒜蒞蒲蒸蒼蒿蓀蓄蓆蓉蓊蓋蓑蓓蓬蓮蓿蔆蔑蔓蔔蔗蔚蔡蔣蔥蔬蔭蔽蕃蕈蕉蕊蕙蕞蕨蕩蕪蕭蕾薄薇薊薑薔薛薜薦薨薩薪薯薰薹薺藉藍藏藐藕藝藤藥藩藪藷藹藺藻蘆蘇蘊蘋蘑蘗蘚蘭蘸蘿虎虐虔處虛虜虞號虧虫虱虹虺虻蚊蚌蚓蚜蚣蚤蚩蚪蚯蚱蚵蚶蛀蛄蛆蛇蛉蛋蛐蛔蛙蛛蛞蛟蛤蛭蛹蛻蛾蜀蜂蜃蜆蜇蜈蜊蜓蜘蜜蜢蜥蜩蜴蜷蜻蜿蝌蝓蝕蝗蝙蝠蝦蝨蝴蝶蝸螂螃融螞螟螢螫螳螺螻蟀蟆蟈蟋蟑蟒蟠蟬蟯蟲蟹蟻蟾蠅蠍蠔蠕蠟蠡蠢蠣蠱蠶蠹蠻血行衍術街衙衛衝衡衢衣表衫衰衷衹衽袁袂袈袋袍袒袖袞被袱裁裂裊裒裔裕裘裙補裝裟裡裨裯裳裴裸裹製褂複褊褐褒褓褕褚褡褥褪褫褲褶褸褻褽襄襖襞襟襠襤襪襬襯襲西要覃覆見規覓視覜覦親覬覲覺覽觀角觔解觴觸觼言訂訃計訊訌討訏訐訑訓訕訖託記訛訝訟訢訣訥訪設許訴訶診註証訾詁詆詐詔評詖詛詞詠詢詣試詨詩詫詬詭詮詰話該詳詹詻詼誅誇誌認誑誓誕誘誚語誠誡誣誤誥誦誧誨說誰課誶誹誼調諂諄談諉請諍諒論諛諜諦諧諫諭諮諱諳諶諷諸諺諼諾謀謁謂謄謊謎謐謗謙講謝謠謨謫謬謹譁譆證譎譏識譙譚譜譟警譫譬譯議譴護譽讀變讒讓讖讚讜谷谿豁豆豈豉豌豎豐豔豕豚象豢豪豫豬豭豳豹豺貂貉貊貌貍貓貝貞負財貢貧貨販貪貫責貯貲貳貴貶買貸費貼貽貿賀賁賂賃賄賅資賈賊賑賒賓賜賞賠賡賢賣賤賦質賬賭賴賸賺賻購賽贅贈贊贍贏贓贖贗贛赤赦赧赫赭走赳赴起趁超越趕趙趟趣趨足趴趺趾跆跋跌跎跑跚跛距跟跡跤跦跨跪路跳跺跼踏踐踝踞踟踡踢踩踫踱踴踵踹蹂蹄蹈蹉蹊蹋蹕蹙蹟蹣蹤蹦蹬蹲蹴蹶蹺蹼躁躂躅躇躉躊躋躍躑躓躡躪身躬躲躺軀車軋軌軍軏軒軔軛軟軸軻軼軾較載輊輒輓輔輕輛輜輝輞輟輥輦輩輪輯輳輸輻輾輿轂轄轅轉轍轎轔轟轡辛辜辟辣辦辨辭辮辯辰辱農迂迄迅迆迎近返迢迤迥迦迨迪迫迭述迴迷迸迺追退送逃逅逆逍透逐途逕逖逗這通逛逝逞速造逢連逮週進逵逶逸逼逾遁遂遇遊運遍過遏遐遑道達違遘遙遛遜遝遞遠遢遣遨適遭遮遲遴遵遷選遺遼遽避邀邁邂邃還邇邈邊邋邏邐邑邕邢那邦邪邱邵邶邸郁郃郊郎郝郡郢部郭郵都郾鄂鄉鄒鄗鄘鄙鄞鄧鄭鄰鄱鄴鄹酈酉酊酋酌配酒酗酣酥酩酪酬酴酵酷酸醃醇醉醋醒醜醞醣醫醬醮醱醴醺釀釁釅釆采釉釋里重野量釐金釗釘釙釜針釣釦釧釩釭釵鈇鈉鈍鈐鈑鈔鈕鈞鈣鈴鈷鈸鈹鈽鈾鈿鉀鉅鉉鉋鉍鉑鉗鉚鉛鉤鉸鉻鉼銀銅銑銓銖銘銜銨銬銲銳銷銻銼鋁鋅鋇鋒鋤鋪鋰鋸鋼錄錐錕錘錙錚錠錡錢錦錨錫錮錯錳錶鍊鍋鍍鍔鍚鍛鍥鍬鍰鍵鍾鎂鎊鎔鎖鎗鎘鎚鎢鎬鎮鎰鎳鏃鏈鏍鏑鏖鏗鏘鏜鏝鏟鏡鏢鏤鏨鏽鐃鐘鐫鐮鐲鐳鐵鐸鐺鑄鑑鑒鑠鑣鑤鑪鑰鑲鑷鑼鑽鑾鑿長門閂閃閉開閎閏閑閒間閔閘閡閣閤閥閨閩閭閱閻闆闈闊闋闌闐闔闕闖關闡闢阜阡阪阬阮阱防阻阿陀陂附陋陌降限陘陛陝陞陡院陣除陪陬陰陲陳陴陵陶陷陸陽隄隅隆隊隋隍階隔隕隘隙際障隧隨險隱隴隸隹隻雀雁雄雅集雇雉雊雋雌雍雒雕雖雙雛雜雞離難雨雩雪雯雲零雷雹電需霄霆震霉霍霎霏霑霓霖霜霞霤霧霪霰露霸霹霽霾靂靄靈青靖靛靜非靠靡面靦靨革靴靶靼鞅鞋鞍鞏鞘鞠鞣鞦鞭韁韃韆韉韋韌韓韜韭音韶韹韻響頁頂頃項順須頊頌預頑頒頓頗領頜頡頤頫頭頰頷頸頹頻顆題額顎顏顓願顛類顥顧顫顯顰顱風颯颱颳颶颺颼飄飛食飢飧飩飪飭飯飲飴飼飽飾餃餅餉養餌餐餒餓餘餚餛餞餡館餮餵餽餾餿饅饉饑饒饕饗饜饞首香馥馨馬馭馮馱馳馴駁駐駑駒駕駙駛駝駟駢駭駱駿騁騎騖騙騫騰騵騷騾驀驃驅驍驕驗驚驛驟驢驥驪骨骯骰骷骸骼髁髏髑髒髓體髖高髡髦髭髮髯髻鬃鬆鬍鬚鬢鬣鬥鬧鬨鬱鬲鬼魁魂魄魅魍魎魏魑魔魘魚魯魷鮑鮪鮫鮭鮮鯀鯈鯉鯊鯖鯛鯧鯨鯽鰍鰓鰥鰭鰱鰻鰾鱉鱔鱖鱗鱟鱷鱸鳥鳩鳳鳴鳶鴃鴆鴉鴒鴕鴛鴣鴦鴨鴻鴿鵑鵝鵠鵡鵪鵬鵲鶉鶯鶴鶸鷂鷓鷗鷥鷹鷺鸚鸛鸞鹵鹹鹼鹽鹿麂麋麒麓麗麝麟麥麩麴麵麻麼麾黃黌黍黎黏黑黔默黛黜黝點黠黨黯黴黷鼇鼎鼓鼕鼙鼠鼬鼯鼴鼻鼾齊齋齒齜齟齡齣齦齧齪齬齲齷龍龐龔龜︰︱︲︳︴︵︶︷︸︹︺︻︼︽︾︿﹀﹁﹂﹃﹄﹉﹊﹋﹌﹍﹎﹏﹐﹑﹒﹔﹕﹖﹗﹘﹙﹚﹛﹜﹝﹞﹟﹠﹡﹢﹣﹤﹥﹦﹨﹩﹪﹫！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～￥
ArialUnicodeMS       1425485     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~·‐‑‒–—―‖‗‘’‚‛“”„․‥…○　、。〃〄々〆〇〈〉《》「」『』【】〒〓〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞一丁七丈三上下不丐丑且丕世丘丙丞丟並丫中丰串丸丹主乃久么之乍乎乏乒乓乖乘乙九乞也乩乳乾亂了予事二于云互五井亙些亞亟亡亢交亥亦亨享京亭亮亳人什仁仃仄仆仇今介仍仔仕他仗付仙仞仟代令以仰仲仳件任份仿企伉伊伋伍伏伐休伕伙伯估伴伶伸伺似伽佃但佇佈位低住佐佑佔何佗余佚佛作佝佞你佣佩佬佯佰佳併佺佻佾使侃來侈例侍侏侑侖供依侮侯侵侶侷便係促俄俊俎俏俐俑俗俘俚保俞俟俠信修俯俱俳俸俺俾倀倆倉個倌倍倏們倒倔倖倘候倚借倡倣倥倦倨倩倪倫倭值偃假偉偌偎偏偕做停健偭偯側偵偶偷偺偽傀傅傍傑傖傘備傚傢催傭傯傲傳債傷傻傾僅僇僎像僑僕僖僚僥僧僩僭僮僱僵價僻儀儂億儅儈儉儐儒儔儕儘償儡優儲儳儷儸儻儼儿兀允元兄充兆兇先光克兌免兒兔兕兗兜兢入內全兩八公六兮共兵其具典兼冀冉冊再冑冒冕冗冠冢冤冥冪冬冰冶冷冽准凋凌凍凜凝几凡凰凱凳凶凸凹出函刀刁刃分切刈刊刎刑划刖列初判別刨利刪刮到制刷券刺刻剁剃則削剋剌前剎剔剖剛剜剝剩剪副割剴創剷剽剿劂劃劇劈劉劊劍劑劓力功加劣助努劫劬劻劾勁勃勇勉勒動勗勘務勛勝勞募勢勣勤勦勰勳勵勸勺勻勾勿包匆匈匍匏匐匕化北匙匝匠匡匣匪匯匱匹匾匿區十千卅升午卉半卑卒卓協南博卜卞占卡卦卮卯印危即卵卷卸卹卻卿厄厚厝原厥厭厲去參又叉及友反叔取受叛叟叢口古句另叨叩只叫召叭叮可台叱史右叵司叻叼吁吃各吆合吉吊吋同名后吏吐向吒君吝吞吟吠否吧吩含听吭吮吱吳吵吶吸吹吻吼吾呀呂呃呆呈告呎呢周呱味呵呶呷呸呻呼命咀咄咆咋和咎咐咒咕咖咚咦咧咨咩咪咫咬咯咱咳咸咻咽咿哀品哂哄哇哈哉哎員哥哦哨哩哪哭哮哲哺哼哽唁唆唇唉唏唐唔唧唬售唯唱唳唷唸唾啁啃啄商啊問啕啖啗啜啞啟啡啣啤啦啪啻啼啾喀喂喃善喇喉喊喋喔喘喙喚喜喝喟喧喪喫喬單喱喲喳喻嗅嗆嗇嗉嗎嗑嗓嗚嗜嗟嗡嗣嗤嗥嗦嗨嗯嗶嗷嗽嗾嘀嘆嘈嘉嘍嘎嘐嘔嘖嘗嘛嘟嘩嘮嘯嘰嘲嘴嘶嘹嘻嘿噎噓噗噙噢噤噥器噩噪噫噬噯噱噴噶噸噹嚀嚅嚇嚎嚏嚐嚕嚥嚨嚮嚴嚶嚷嚼囀囁囂囈囉囊囌囑囚四囝回因囤囪囫困固囿圃圄圈圉國圍園圓圖團土在圩圬圭圯地圳圻圾址均坊坍坎坏坐坑坡坤坦坩坪坷坼垂垃型垓垠垢垣垮埂埃埋城埔域埠埤執培基堂堅堆堉堊堝堠堡堤堪堯堰報場堵塊塋塌塑塒塔塗塘塚塞塢填塭塵塹塽塾墀境墅墊墓墜增墟墦墨墩墮墳墾壁壅壇壎壑壓壕壘壙壞壟壢壤壩士壬壯壹壺壽夏夔夕外夙多夜夠夢夤夥大天太夫夭央失夷夸夾奄奇奈奉奎奏奐契奔奕套奘奚奠奢奧奩奪奭奮女奴奶奸她好妁如妃妄妊妍妒妓妖妙妝妞妣妤妥妨妮妯妳妹妻妾姅姆姊始姍姐姑姒姓委姘姚姜姣姥姦姨姪姬姻姿威娃娉娌娑娓娘娛娜娟娠娣娥娩娶娼婀婁婆婉婊婚婢婦婪婷婿媒媚媛媧媲媳媼媽媾嫁嫂嫉嫌嫖嫗嫘嫡嫣嫦嫩嫵嫻嬈嬉嬋嬌嬝嬤嬪嬰嬴嬸孀孃子孑孓孔孕字存孚孛孜孝孟季孤孩孫孰孱孳孵學孺孽孿它宅宇守安宋完宏宗官宙定宛宜客宣室宥宦宮宰害宴宵家宸容宿寂寄寅密寇富寐寒寓寞察寡寢寤寥實寧寨審寫寬寮寰寵寶寸寺封射將專尉尊尋對導小少尖尚尢尤尬就尷尸尹尺尼尾尿局屁居屆屈屋屍屎屏屐屑展屘屜屝屠屢層履屨屬屯山屹岌岐岑岔岡岩岫岱岳岷岸峒峙峨峪峭峰峴島峻峽崁崆崇崎崑崔崖崗崙崛崢崤崧崩崴嵇嵌嵐嵩嵯嶄嶇嶔嶝嶸嶺嶼嶽巉巍巒巔巖川州巡巢工左巧巨巫差己已巳巴巷巽巾市布帆希帑帕帖帘帚帛帝帟帥師席帳帶帷常帽幀幃幅幌幔幕幗幛幟幡幢幣幫干平年并幸幹幻幼幽幾庇床序底庖店庚府庠度座庫庭庵庶康庸庾廁廂廄廈廉廊廓廖廚廝廟廠廢廣廬廳延廷建廾廿弁弄弈弊弋式弒弓弔引弗弘弛弟弦弧弩弭弱張強弼彆彈彊彌彎彗彙彝形彤彥彩彪彫彬彭彰影彷役彼彿往征待徇很徉徊律後徐徑徒得徘徙徜從徠御徨復循徬微徵德徹徽心必忌忍忖志忘忙忝忠忪快忱念忸忽忿怎怏怒怔怕怖怛思怠怡急性怨怩怪怫怯怵恃恆恍恐恕恙恢恣恤恥恨恩恪恫恬恭息恰恿悄悅悉悌悍悔悖悚悟悠患您悲悴悵悶悸悻悼悽情惆惇惋惑惕惘惚惜惟惠惡惦惰惱想惴惶惹惺惻愀愁愆愈愉愍愎意愒愕愚愛愜感愣愧愴愷愾愿慄慇慈態慌慍慎慕慘慚慝慟慢慣慧慨慫慮慰慵慶慷慼慾憂憊憎憐憑憔憚憤憧憩憫憬憮憲憶憾懂懇懈應懊懋懍懣懦懲懵懶懷懸懺懼懾懿戀戈戊戌戍戎成我戒戕或戚戛戟戡戢截戮戰戲戳戴戶戾房所扁扇扈扉手才扎扑扒打扔托扛扣扭扮扯扳扶批扼找承技抄抆抉把抑抒抓投抖抗折抨披抬抱抵抹押抽抿拂拄拆拇拈拉拋拌拍拎拐拒拓拔拖拗拘拙拚招拜括拭拮拯拱拳拴拷拼拽拾拿持挂指挈按挑挖挨挪挫振挺挽挾捂捆捉捌捍捎捏捐捕捧捨捩捫捱捲捶捷捺捻掀掃掄授掉掌掏排掖掘掙掛掠採探掣接控推掩措掬揀揆揉揍描提插揖揚換握揣揩揪揭揮援揹搆損搏搓搔搖搗搜搞搪搬搭搴搶搽搾摑摒摔摘摟摧摩摭摯摸摹摺摻撇撈撐撒撓撕撙撚撞撢撤撥撩撫撬播撮撰撲撳撻撼撾撿擁擂擄擅擇擊擋操擎擒擔擘據擠擢擦擬擭擰擱擲擴擷擺擻擾攀攆攏攔攘攙攜攝攣攤攪攫攬支收攸改攻放政故效敉敏救敔敕敖敗敘教敝敞敢散敦敬敲整敵敷數斂斃文斐斑斕斗料斛斜斟斡斤斥斧斫斬斯新斷方於施旁旅旋旌旎族旖旗既日旦旨早旬旭旱旺昀昂昆昇昊昌明昏易昔昕星映昤春昧昨昭是昱晁時晃晅晉晌晏晒晚晝晞晤晦晨普景晰晴晶晷智晾暄暇暈暉暍暑暖暗暘暝暢暨暫暮暱暴暸暹曄曆曇曉曖曙曜曝曠曦曩曬曰曲曳更曷書曹曼曾替最會月有朋服朔朕朗望朝期朦朧木未末本札朮朱朴朵朽杆杉李杏材村杓杖杗杜杞束杠杪杭杯杰東杲杳杵杷杼松板枇枉枋析枓枕林枚果枝枯枰枴架枸柄柏某柑柒染柔柙柚柝柞柢查柩柬柯柱柳柴柵柿栓栗栘校栩株核根格栽桀桁桂桃桅框案桌桐桑桓桔桶桿梁梂梃梅梆梓梔梗條梟梡梢梧梨梭梯械梱梳梵棄棉棋棍棒棕棗棘棚棟棠棣棧森棲棵棹棺棻椅植椎椒椰楊楓楔楚楛楝楞楠楣楨楫業楮極楷楹概榆榔榕榛榜榣榦榨榫榭榮榴榷榻槁槃構槌槍槐槓槨槭槳槽樁樂樅樊樑樓標樞樟模樣樵樸樹樺樽橄橇橈橋橘橙機橡橢橫橾檀檄檐檔檗檜檠檢檣檬檮檯檳檸檻櫂櫃櫓櫚櫛櫝櫥櫬櫺櫻欄權欐欖欠次欣欲欺欽款歇歉歌歎歐歙歜歟歡止正此步武歧歪歲歷歸歹死歿殃殆殉殊殖殘殤殮殯殲段殷殺殼殿毀毅毆毋母每毒毓比毗毚毛毫毬毯毽氅氈氏氐民氓氖氛氟氣氤氦氧氨氫氬氮氯氳水永氾汀汁求汍汎汐汕汗汙汛汝汞江池污汨汪汰汲汴汶決汽汾沁沂沃沅沆沈沉沌沍沐沒沔沖沘沙沛沫沬沮沱河沸油治沼沽沾沿況泄泅泉泊泌泓法泖泗泛泜泠泡波泣泥注泯泰泱泳泵洋洌洎洗洛洞津洧洩洪洫洮洱洲洵洶洸洹活洽派流浙浚浥浦浩浪浬浮浴海浸浹涅涇消涉涊涌涎涓涔涕涪涮涯液涵涸涼涿淄淅淆淇淋淌淑淒淘淙淚淞淡淤淦淨淪淫淬淮深淳淵混淹淺添清渙渚減渝渠渡渣渤渥渦測渭港渲渴游渺渾湃湄湊湍湎湔湖湘湛湟湣湧湩湮湯湲溉源準溘溜溝溢溥溧溪溫溯溴溶溺溼滂滄滅滇滋滌滑滓滔滕滬滯滲滴滷滾滿漁漂漆漏漓演漕漠漢漣漩漪漫漬漯漱漲漳漸漾漿潑潔潘潛潟潠潤潦潭潮潯潰潸潺潼澀澄澆澈澎澗澠澡澤澦澧澱澳澴澶澹激濁濂濃濕濘濛濟濠濡濤濩濫濬濮濯濰濱濺濾瀆瀉瀋瀏瀑瀕瀘瀚瀛瀝瀟瀨瀰瀲瀾灌灑灘灞灣灤火灰灶灸灼災炊炎炒炕炙炤炫炬炭炮炯炳炸為烈烊烏烘烙烤烯烹烽焉焊焙焚焜無焦焰然煆煉煌煎煖煙煜煞煤煥煦照煨煩煬煮煽熄熊熒熔熙熟熨熬熱熹熾燃燄燈燉燎燐燒燕燙燜營燠燥燦燧燬燭燮燴燸燻燼燾爆爍爐爛爨爪爬爭爰爵父爸爹爺爻爽爾牆片版牌牒牖牘牙牛牝牟牠牡牢牧物牯牲牴特牽犀犁犄犒犖犛犢犧犬犯狀狂狄狎狐狗狙狠狡狩狷狸狹狼狽猓猖猙猛猜猥猩猴猶猷猾猿獄獅獎獐獗獨獰獲獵獷獸獺獻玀玄玆率玉王玖玟玥玨玩玫玲玳玷玻珀珊珍珞珠珪班珮現球琅理琉琊琍琛琢琥琦琨琪琯琳琴琵琶琺琿瑁瑕瑙瑚瑛瑜瑞瑟瑣瑤瑩瑪瑭瑯瑰瑾璀璃璋璘璜璞璟璣璦璧璨璩環璽璿瓊瓏瓔瓖瓚瓜瓠瓢瓣瓤瓦瓶瓷甄甌甍甕甘甚甜生產甥甦用甩甫甬甭田由甲申男甸甽畋界畎畏畔留畚畜畝畢略畦番畫異當畸畿疆疇疊疋疏疑疙疚疝疢疣疤疥疫疲疳疵疸疹疼疽疾痂病症痊痍痔痕痘痙痛痞痠痢痣痰痱痲痳痴痺痿瘀瘁瘉瘋瘍瘓瘟瘠瘡瘢瘤瘦瘧瘩瘴瘸瘺療癆癌癒癖癘癟癡癢癥癩癬癮癱癲癸登發白百皂的皆皇皈皋皎皓皖皚皮皰皴皺皿盂盃盅盆盈益盍盎盒盔盛盜盞盟盡監盤盥盧盪目盯盲直相盹盼盾省眇眉看真眠眨眩眶眷眸眺眼眾睏睛睜睞睡睢督睥睦睨睪睫睬睹睽睿瞄瞇瞋瞌瞎瞑瞞瞟瞠瞥瞧瞪瞬瞭瞰瞳瞻瞼瞽瞿矇矓矗矚矛矜矢矣知矩短矮矯石矽砂砌砍研砝砟砠砥砧砭砰砲破砷砸硃硎硝硫硬硯硼硿碉碌碎碑碓碗碘碟碣碧碩碰碳確碼碾磁磅磊磋磐磕磚磧磨磬磯磴磷磺礁礎礙礦礪礫礬示社祀祁祆祇祈祉祐祕祖祗祚祝神祟祠祥票祭祺祿禁禍禎福禦禧禪禮禱禳禹禺禽禾禿秀私秈秉秋科秒秘租秣秤秦秧秩移稀稅稈程稍稔稚稜稞稟稠種稱稷稻稼稽稿穀穆穋穌積穎穗穠穡穢穩穫穴究穹空穿突窄窈窒窕窖窗窘窟窠窩窪窮窯窺窿竄竅竇竊立站竟章竣童竭端競竹竺竽竿笆笑笙笛笞笠符笨第笮筆等筋筍筏筐筑筒答策筠筧筮筵筷箄箇箋箏箔箕算箝箠管箭箱箴箸節篁範篆篇築篌篙篛篠篡篤篦篩篷篾簇簌簍簑簞簡簣簧簪簫簷簸簽簾簿籀籃籌籍籐籟籠籣籤籥籬籮米籽粉粒粕粗粟粥粱粳粵粹粽精糊糕糖糙糜糝糞糟糠糢糧糯糰糸系糾紀紂約紅紆紇紉紊紋納紐純紕紗紙級紛紜素紡索紫紮累細紱紲紳紹紼絀終絃組絆結絕絛絞絡絢給絨絮絰統絲絳絹綁綏綑經綜綞綠綢綬維綰綱網綴綵綸綺綻綽綾綿緇緊緒緘緙線緝緞締緣編緩緬緯緲練緹緻縈縉縊縐縑縛縝縞縣縫縮縯縱縲縴縵縷縹總績縿繁繃繅繆繈繒織繕繙繚繞繡繩繪繫繭繳繹繼繽纂續纏纓纔纖纜缶缸缺缽罄罈罌罐罔罕罟罩罪置罰署罵罷罹羅羈羊羋羌美羔羚羞群羨義羯羲羶羸羹羼羽羿翁翅翌翎習翔翕翟翠翡翩翮翰翱翳翹翻翼耀老考耄者耆耋而耍耐耑耒耕耗耘耙耜耦耨耳耶耽耿聆聊聒聖聘聚聞聯聰聱聲聳聶職聽聾聿肄肅肆肇肉肋肌肓肖肘肚肛肝股肢肥肩肪肫肯肱育肴肺胃胄背胎胖胚胛胝胞胡胤胥胭胯胰胱胳胴胸胼能脂脅脆脈脊脖脣脤脩脫脯脰脹脾腆腋腌腎腐腑腓腔腕腥腦腫腮腰腱腳腴腸腹腺腿膀膂膈膊膏膘膚膛膜膝膠膨膩膳膺膽膾膿臀臂臃臆臉臍臏臘臚臟臢臣臥臧臨自臬臭至致臺臻臼臾舀舂舅與興舉舊舌舍舐舒舔舛舜舞舟舢舨航舫般舵舶舷船艇艋艘艙艦艮良艱色艷艾芋芍芒芙芝芟芣芥芬芭芯芰花芳芷芸芹芻芽芾苑苒苓苔苗苛苜苞苟苣若苦苧苯英茁茂范茄茅茆茉茗茨茫茱茲茴茵茶茸茹荀荃草荊荏荐荒荔荷荸荻荼莆莉莊莎莒莓莖莘莞莠莢莧莫莽菁菅菊菌菔菜菟菠菩華菰菱菲菴菸菽萃萄萇萊萋萌萍萎萬萱萵萸萼落葆葉著葛葡董葦葩葫葬葭葵葷蒂蒐蒙蒜蒞蒲蒸蒼蒿蓀蓄蓆蓉蓊蓋蓑蓓蓬蓮蓿蔆蔑蔓蔔蔗蔚蔡蔣蔥蔬蔭蔽蕃蕈蕉蕊蕙蕞蕨蕩蕪蕭蕾薄薇薊薑薔薛薜薦薨薩薪薯薰薹薺藉藍藏藐藕藝藤藥藩藪藷藹藺藻蘆蘇蘊蘋蘑蘗蘚蘭蘸蘿虎虐虔處虛虜虞號虧虫虱虹虺虻蚊蚌蚓蚜蚣蚤蚩蚪蚯蚱蚵蚶蛀蛄蛆蛇蛉蛋蛐蛔蛙蛛蛞蛟蛤蛭蛹蛻蛾蜀蜂蜃蜆蜇蜈蜊蜓蜘蜜蜢蜥蜩蜴蜷蜻蜿蝌蝓蝕蝗蝙蝠蝦蝨蝴蝶蝸螂螃融螞螟螢螫螳螺螻蟀蟆蟈蟋蟑蟒蟠蟬蟯蟲蟹蟻蟾蠅蠍蠔蠕蠟蠡蠢蠣蠱蠶蠹蠻血行衍術街衙衛衝衡衢衣表衫衰衷衹衽袁袂袈袋袍袒袖袞被袱裁裂裊裒裔裕裘裙補裝裟裡裨裯裳裴裸裹製褂複褊褐褒褓褕褚褡褥褪褫褲褶褸褻褽襄襖襞襟襠襤襪襬襯襲西要覃覆見規覓視覜覦親覬覲覺覽觀角觔解觴觸觼言訂訃計訊訌討訏訐訑訓訕訖託記訛訝訟訢訣訥訪設許訴訶診註証訾詁詆詐詔評詖詛詞詠詢詣試詨詩詫詬詭詮詰話該詳詹詻詼誅誇誌認誑誓誕誘誚語誠誡誣誤誥誦誧誨說誰課誶誹誼調諂諄談諉請諍諒論諛諜諦諧諫諭諮諱諳諶諷諸諺諼諾謀謁謂謄謊謎謐謗謙講謝謠謨謫謬謹譁譆證譎譏識譙譚譜譟警譫譬譯議譴護譽讀變讒讓讖讚讜谷谿豁豆豈豉豌豎豐豔豕豚象豢豪豫豬豭豳豹豺貂貉貊貌貍貓貝貞負財貢貧貨販貪貫責貯貲貳貴貶買貸費貼貽貿賀賁賂賃賄賅資賈賊賑賒賓賜賞賠賡賢賣賤賦質賬賭賴賸賺賻購賽贅贈贊贍贏贓贖贗贛赤赦赧赫赭走赳赴起趁超越趕趙趟趣趨足趴趺趾跆跋跌跎跑跚跛距跟跡跤跦跨跪路跳跺跼踏踐踝踞踟踡踢踩踫踱踴踵踹蹂蹄蹈蹉蹊蹋蹕蹙蹟蹣蹤蹦蹬蹲蹴蹶蹺蹼躁躂躅躇躉躊躋躍躑躓躡躪身躬躲躺軀車軋軌軍軏軒軔軛軟軸軻軼軾較載輊輒輓輔輕輛輜輝輞輟輥輦輩輪輯輳輸輻輾輿轂轄轅轉轍轎轔轟轡辛辜辟辣辦辨辭辮辯辰辱農迂迄迅迆迎近返迢迤迥迦迨迪迫迭述迴迷迸迺追退送逃逅逆逍透逐途逕逖逗這通逛逝逞速造逢連逮週進逵逶逸逼逾遁遂遇遊運遍過遏遐遑道達違遘遙遛遜遝遞遠遢遣遨適遭遮遲遴遵遷選遺遼遽避邀邁邂邃還邇邈邊邋邏邐邑邕邢那邦邪邱邵邶邸郁郃郊郎郝郡郢部郭郵都郾鄂鄉鄒鄗鄘鄙鄞鄧鄭鄰鄱鄴鄹酈酉酊酋酌配酒酗酣酥酩酪酬酴酵酷酸醃醇醉醋醒醜醞醣醫醬醮醱醴醺釀釁釅釆采釉釋里重野量釐金釗釘釙釜針釣釦釧釩釭釵鈇鈉鈍鈐鈑鈔鈕鈞鈣鈴鈷鈸鈹鈽鈾鈿鉀鉅鉉鉋鉍鉑鉗鉚鉛鉤鉸鉻鉼銀銅銑銓銖銘銜銨銬銲銳銷銻銼鋁鋅鋇鋒鋤鋪鋰鋸鋼錄錐錕錘錙錚錠錡錢錦錨錫錮錯錳錶鍊鍋鍍鍔鍚鍛鍥鍬鍰鍵鍾鎂鎊鎔鎖鎗鎘鎚鎢鎬鎮鎰鎳鏃鏈鏍鏑鏖鏗鏘鏜鏝鏟鏡鏢鏤鏨鏽鐃鐘鐫鐮鐲鐳鐵鐸鐺鑄鑑鑒鑠鑣鑤鑪鑰鑲鑷鑼鑽鑾鑿長門閂閃閉開閎閏閑閒間閔閘閡閣閤閥閨閩閭閱閻闆闈闊闋闌闐闔闕闖關闡闢阜阡阪阬阮阱防阻阿陀陂附陋陌降限陘陛陝陞陡院陣除陪陬陰陲陳陴陵陶陷陸陽隄隅隆隊隋隍階隔隕隘隙際障隧隨險隱隴隸隹隻雀雁雄雅集雇雉雊雋雌雍雒雕雖雙雛雜雞離難雨雩雪雯雲零雷雹電需霄霆震霉霍霎霏霑霓霖霜霞霤霧霪霰露霸霹霽霾靂靄靈青靖靛靜非靠靡面靦靨革靴靶靼鞅鞋鞍鞏鞘鞠鞣鞦鞭韁韃韆韉韋韌韓韜韭音韶韹韻響頁頂頃項順須頊頌預頑頒頓頗領頜頡頤頫頭頰頷頸頹頻顆題額顎顏顓願顛類顥顧顫顯顰顱風颯颱颳颶颺颼飄飛食飢飧飩飪飭飯飲飴飼飽飾餃餅餉養餌餐餒餓餘餚餛餞餡館餮餵餽餾餿饅饉饑饒饕饗饜饞首香馥馨馬馭馮馱馳馴駁駐駑駒駕駙駛駝駟駢駭駱駿騁騎騖騙騫騰騵騷騾驀驃驅驍驕驗驚驛驟驢驥驪骨骯骰骷骸骼髁髏髑髒髓體髖高髡髦髭髮髯髻鬃鬆鬍鬚鬢鬣鬥鬧鬨鬱鬲鬼魁魂魄魅魍魎魏魑魔魘魚魯魷鮑鮪鮫鮭鮮鯀鯈鯉鯊鯖鯛鯧鯨鯽鰍鰓鰥鰭鰱鰻鰾鱉鱔鱖鱗鱟鱷鱸鳥鳩鳳鳴鳶鴃鴆鴉鴒鴕鴛鴣鴦鴨鴻鴿鵑鵝鵠鵡鵪鵬鵲鶉鶯鶴鶸鷂鷓鷗鷥鷹鷺鸚鸛鸞鹵鹹鹼鹽鹿麂麋麒麓麗麝麟麥麩麴麵麻麼麾黃黌黍黎黏黑黔默黛黜黝點黠黨黯黴黷鼇鼎鼓鼕鼙鼠鼬鼯鼴鼻鼾齊齋齒齜齟齡齣齦齧齪齬齲齷龍龐龔龜︰︱︲︳︴︵︶︷︸︹︺︻︼︽︾︿﹀﹁﹂﹃﹄﹉﹊﹋﹌﹍﹎﹏﹐﹑﹒﹔﹕﹖﹗﹘﹙﹚﹛﹜﹝﹞﹟﹠﹡﹢﹣﹤﹥﹦﹨﹩﹪﹫！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～￥

ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
             74611    Scene 1:Frame 1





embeddedCFF
false
517 517
Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embedded
Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embeddedCFF
Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embeddedCFF
```

And here are the two classes I use for the Flex SDK tests:

```
package fonts
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class FontChinese extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source='/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf', 
        fontName='_Arial',
        mimeType='application/x-font-truetype',
        unicodeRange='U+4EBA,U+4EBA,U+751F,U+800C,U+81EA,U+7531,U+FF0C,U+5728,U+5C0A,U+4E25,U+548C,U+6743,U+5229,U+4E0A,U+4E00,U+5F8B,U+5E73,U+7B49,U+3002,U+4ED6,U+4EEC,U+8D4B,U+6709,U+7406,U+6027,U+548C,U+826F,U+5FC3,U+FF0C,U+5E76,U+5E94,U+4EE5,U+5144,U+5F1F,U+5173,U+7CFB,U+7684,U+7CBE,U+795E,U+76F8,U+5BF9,U+5F85,U+3002,U+000D,U+000A,U+2029,U+0020,U+4E00-U+4FFF', 
        embedAsCFF='true')]
        public static var _Arial:Class;

        public function FontChinese()
        {
            trace("** embed Arial Chinese**");
        }
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
package fonts
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.engine.*;
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    import flashx.textLayout.container.*;
    import flashx.textLayout.conversion.*;
    import flashx.textLayout.elements.*;
    import flashx.textLayout.factory.*;
    import flashx.textLayout.formats.*;

    public class FontTest extends Sprite
    {

        private var fontLoader:Loader;
        private var fontURL:String = 'FontChinese.swf';//'FontLatinExt.swf';
        private var sampleText:String;
        public function FontTest()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void{
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            fontLoader = new Loader();
            fontLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,fontReady);
            fontLoader.load(new URLRequest(fontURL));
            //sampleText = "compañero"; for (var i:int = 32; i < 500; i++) sampleText += String.fromCharCode(i) + (i%50==0?'\n':'');
            sampleText = '';for(var i:int = 19968; i < 20479; i++) sampleText += String.fromCharCode(i);
        }
        private function fontReady(event:Event):void{
            var FontLibrary : Class = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("fonts."+fontURL.split('.')[0]) as Class;
            trace(FontLibrary);
            Font.registerFont(FontLibrary._Arial);
            trace(Font.enumerateFonts()[0].fontName);           
            var t:TextField = addChild(new TextField) as TextField;
            t.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(FontLibrary._Arial.fontName);
            t.embedFonts = true;
            t.multiline = t.border = true;
            t.rotation = 5;
            t.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            t.wordWrap = true;
            t.width = stage.stageWidth;
            t.text = sampleText+'\n'+describeType(FontLibrary._Arial);

            var tlf:Sprite = addChild(TextFactory.getText(t.text,'body',true,false,t.width,uint(t.defaultTextFormat.size),0)) as Sprite;
            tlf.y = t.height;
        }
        public function getText(text : String, type : String, multiline : Boolean, html : Boolean, width : Number = NaN, fontSize : uint = 0, color : uint = 0xFFFFFF, forceCenter : Boolean = false) : Sprite {
            var cont : Sprite = new Sprite;
            var controller : ContainerController = new ContainerController(cont, width, NaN);
            var textFlow : TextFlow;
            if (!html) {
                textFlow = new TextFlow;
                var span : SpanElement = new SpanElement();
                span.text = text;
                var p : ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
                p.addChild(span);
                textFlow.addChild(p);
            } else {
                textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.HTML_FORMAT);
            }
            textFlow.whiteSpaceCollapse = true;
            textFlow.lineBreak = multiline ? LineBreak.TO_FIT : LineBreak.EXPLICIT ;
            textFlow.format = getFormat(TextLayoutFormat(textFlow.computedFormat), fontSize, color);
            textFlow.flowComposer.addController(controller);
            textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();

            return cont;
        }
        public static function getFormat(baseFormat : TextLayoutFormat, size : uint, color : uint) : TextLayoutFormat {
            var charFormat : TextLayoutFormat = baseFormat;
            charFormat.color = color;
            charFormat.whiteSpaceCollapse = true;
            charFormat.fontLookup = FontManager.bodyFont.substr(0, 1) == "_" ? FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF : FontLookup.DEVICE;
            trace('FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF',FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF);
            charFormat.fontFamily = FontManager.bodyFont;
            charFormat.fontSize = size;
            charFormat.lineHeight = charFormat.fontSize * 1.4;
            charFormat.dominantBaseline = TextBaseline.ROMAN;
            charFormat.direction = Direction.LTR;
            charFormat.justificationRule = JustificationRule.SPACE;
            charFormat.textAlign = TextAlign.START;
            charFormat.textAlignLast = TextAlign.START;
            charFormat.blockProgression = BlockProgression.TB;
            return charFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you embedding the font?  Are you embedding anything else?  Are you positive that `embed=true` on your TLF textfield?  Are you using any bolding and/or italics?

I have embedded Chinese w/ Arial Unicode MS before, but it could have actually been simplified Chinese and it was in the pre-TLF days.

Three things to try:

1. Generate a size report.  It will show the font embeds, the glyphs that got embedded, and a count.
2. Whenever I have font problems, I use the old school method of font embedding.  Create a dynamic text field on stage somewhere on frame 1, but off screen.  Set the embed on this via the checkbox in the popup.  I do this for all four combinations of bold and italic on/off.
3. Add this somewhere in your code to check the embeds.

```
var fonts : Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
fonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

for (var i : int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
  trace("Fonts()", fonts[i].fontName, fonts[i].fontStyle, fonts[i].fontType);
}
```

This will show you what the VM actually thinks are available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. VM thinks it has the font, and they show up in the size report (even though not in the paste here on SO) - size report is also available [here](file:///Users/georgeprofenza/Desktop/ChineseEmbedTestTLF.txt), but you need to open that in a decent text editor

Comment: 1. Done, 2. That is how I've done the embed with Flash, 3. I get this output: Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embedded
Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embeddedCFF
Fonts() Arial Unicode MS regular embeddedCFF

Comment: Everything looks correct.  Have you tried another font w/ the gyphs you need?

Comment: Quick update: I have found a font that embeds more glyphs and it can display all the text I currently need to display. The problem is users will submit text, so they might input/try to input characters that couldn't be embedded and will be rendered with the device font. If anybody wonder, currently the font I'm using is 华文黑体.ttf  Any font suggestion would help

Comment: Are you developing this for a client?  They should be able to give you a good font to use.  Otherwise, the last time I did this I picked one of the default Chinese fonts that was included with both Windows 2000 and Windows XP.  I can't find my notes, though, on which I used.